# linq keyword searching with contains

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string

Ok guys this makes no sense...

I have this method:

```
// break down the search terms in to individual keywords
string[] searchTerms = ui_txtSearch.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// get the complete list of companies
List<Company> results = Company.List();
// foreach keyword
for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.Length; i++)
{
    // results = the existing result set - the items that dont meet the current search term results.
    results = (from comp in results
           where comp.Name.Contains(searchTerms[i]
           select comp).ToList();
}
```

Now the general idea is that from the list of companies I want all that contain all of the keywords in the search term provided in my textbox on the ui.

My problem is this "Contains" (highlighted above in **) ... if I have say "Company" in the Name string and I search for "Co" i expect it to that as a result because the name would contain that but it doesn't ...

any ideas ?

EDIT:

Ok i found that the problem was case sensitivity so i refactored the code to this:

```
// break down the search terms in to individual keywords
string[] searchTerms = ui_txtSearch.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// get the complete list of companies
List<Company> results = Company.List();
// foreach keyword
for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.Length; i++)
{
    // results = the existing result set - the items that dont meet the current search term results.
    results = (
        from comp in results
        where comp.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(searchTerms[i].ToLower()) > -1
        select comp
        ).ToList();
}
```

To address some of your feedback below:

The search term might be something like "Test Company 1", I am looking for all results where "test" and "company" and "1" can be found in the company name and the result set must contain all search keywords presented when the full search term is split by " ".

the cleanest way to do this is with a loop as i understand it??? ... or am i wrong ?

so i basically read this as ...

1. get a list of all companies
2. filter list by search term 1
3. from filtered list filter by search term N ... and repeat until all terms are considered.
4. the result set will now contain all search terms provided in the company name.

The current code seems to work and sort of answers my question ... but do you guys think theres a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks for the help all :)

EDIT 2:

Thanks to all the help given below I believe the final version (still testing) should be this:

```
// break down the search terms in to individual keywords
string[] searchTerms = ui_txtSearch.Text.ToLower().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// get the complete list of companies
List<Company> results;
// results = the existing result set - the items that dont meet the current search term results.
results = (
    from comp in Company.List()
    where searchTerms.All(s => comp.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(s) > -1)
    select comp
    ).ToList();
```

thank you everyone :)

Comment: you sould put change the query inside the loop for this: results = results.where(comp.Name.Contains(searchTerms[i])), and remove the "Tolist". Call the .tolist only once after the loop. Maybe it will not solve your problem, but I think its the right way to do it.

Comment: hi jonathon ... the ToList call ensures the filtered result from each loop operation is always of type List<Company> rather than a ResultGroup or whatever it is that linq natively returns (it appears to work much like an arraylist or dictionary object). This call ensures that the same type is queried and eventually used in my databinding process after this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reassigning `results` on every iteration. But it also looks to me like you can just replace your entire code with this:

```
string[] searchTerms = ui_txtSearch.Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var results = (from comp in Company.List()
              where searchTerms.All(s => comp.Contains(s))
              select comp).ToList();
```

That should be a little more in line with what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats deliberate to ensure that on the second iteration i only search what has passed the linq query from the first iteration.

Comment: @Wardy: In that case, the above code using `All()` is definitely what you want. If you did decide to go with a `for` loop, you'd be better off using a different variable than `results` inside the loop and using `ToList` only at the very end. That way, LINQ would be able to compose all your `where` clauses into one. But the `All` code would do essentially the same thing, in the same time and possibly even faster.

Comment: Ah ok ... (edited above to reflect this) Thank you for the answer Justin.

Comment: use just `new[] { ' ' }` or `new[] { " " }` to get my +1

Comment: @abatishchev - Good call. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the loop is assigning the final result to `results`, which is also the data being searched.  So if the `Co` value is the second item in the `searchTerms`, it likely won't find it since it would have been cleared on the first iteration.

Comment: thats a good point ... but my final results set should include all search keywords provided not just 1.

Answer (score 1):

"Results" is being re-assigned on each iteration, so the results would be only the results from the last search term in the array. You're also missing a closing paren for the "Contains" method. Off the top of my head, I'd say you'd probably have to do something like:

1. Use a different list variable to hold the results (like "finalResults") and only query the original list.
2. Add to the built up list: finalResults.AddRange((linq query).ToList());
3. filter the final results with a distinct clause to weed out dupes

Comment: the reassign is deliberate so i only search on the second loop what passed the term compare on the first loop instead of searching all company data again only to then have to check which ones are new. Does that make sense ?